# Best way to replace a char beetween to quote in python

Tags: python

I have a file with a line like:

```
1,2,"toto , titi",3"titi ,, tata",4
```

And I would like to replace each comma `,` that is beeween quotes (`"`) with a colon `:`

So my outout should be :

```
1,2,"toto : titi",3"titi :: tata",4
```

I am thinking about splitting by `"` but I think there are betters ways.

Comment: If this is a CSV file, you could use the cvs module to read each line, replace all commas in all parsed fields with colons, then write them back out.

Comment: I think you're looking for the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module. Otherwise, you'll need to roll your own parser. (Which is not difficult, but will be a bit bulky and slow if you're writing it in python.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this you could use a regex:

```
import re

string = '1,2,"toto , titi",3"titi ,, tata",4'

print(re.sub('".*?"',  lambda x: x.group().replace(',', ':'), string)) #Output 1,2,"toto : titi",3"titi :: tata",4
```

The `sub` method from the `re` module replaces with the help of a regex.

For the regex, you should use a non greedy pattern `.*?` to avoid the `,3` being replaced with `:3`

You can test the [regex online](https://regex101.com/r/aIBJDY/1)

And then I replace with a lambda function by replacing the commas in the matching group by.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are parsing CSV file using [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module, as [@Mateen Ulhaq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365102/mateen-ulhaq) and [@Tom Karzes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5460719/tom-karzes) mentioned, would be the best option.

However if you don't want to use this module you could implement it yourself. **Assuming you always have correct (even) number of quotes** what you can do is:

1. Split by quotes
2. replace `,` with `:` in every **odd** substring
3. join with quote

It could be done in single line:

```
 s = '1,2,"toto , titi",3"titi ,, tata",4'   
 result = '"'.join(w.replace(',',':') if i%2 else w for i,w in enumerate(s.split('"')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one with regex:

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> text = '1,2,"toto , titi",3"titi ,, tata",4'
>>> re.sub(r'(".+?")', lambda m: m.group(1).replace(',', ':'), text)
'1,2,"toto : titi",3"titi :: tata",4'
```

Answer (score 0):

not a regex solution

```
x='1,2,"toto , titi",3"titi ,, tata",4'


def fun(x):
    check = 'False'
    x=list(x)
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if x[i]=='"' and check == 'False':
            check = 'True'
        elif x[i]=='"' and check =='True':
            check = 'False'
        elif check =='True' and x[i]==',':
            x[i]=':'
        else:
            pass
    return ''.join(x)

print(fun(x))

# output '1,2,"toto : titi",3"titi :: tata",4'
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that line is always correct (number of `"` is multiply of `2`) I would do it following way:

```
line = '1,2,"toto , titi",3"titi ,, tata",4'
out = ''.join([i.replace(',',':') if line[inx+1:].count('"')%2 else i for inx,i in enumerate(line)])
print(out) # 1,2,"toto : titi",3"titi :: tata",4
```

This method is working as follows: iterate over characters in `line`, for each get substring which is to right of given character, if there is odd number of `"` inside that substring replace `,` with `:` otherwise left character as is.